# how can i use grid.py for parameter selection?

Tags: libsvm

i want to select parameters c and gamma for C-SVM classification using
the RBF (radial basis function) kernel with libsvm\tools\grid.py, but i dont know how it's possible? i installed libsvm and gnuplot and python and runned the grid.py in python, but it had error and didn't show the results.

Answer (score 12):

```
%grid of parameters
folds = 5; 
[C,gamma] = meshgrid(-5:2:15, -15:2:3); 
%# grid search, and cross-validation 
cv_acc = zeros(numel(C),1); 
d= 2;
for i=1:numel(C)   
    cv_acc(i) = svmtrain(TrainLabel,TrainVec, ...          
        sprintf('-c %f -g %f -v %d -t %d', 2^C(i), 2^gamma(i), folds,d));
end
%# pair (C,gamma) with best accuracy
[~,idx] = max(cv_acc); 
%# contour plot of paramter selection 
contour(C, gamma, reshape(cv_acc,size(C))), colorbar
hold on;
text(C(idx), gamma(idx), sprintf('Acc = %.2f %%',cv_acc(idx)), ...  
    'HorizontalAlign','left', 'VerticalAlign','top') 
hold off 
xlabel('log_2(C)'), ylabel('log_2(\gamma)'), title('Cross-Validation Accuracy') 
%# now you can train you model using best_C and best_gamma
best_C = 2^C(idx); best_gamma = 2^gamma(idx); %# ...
```

This performs grid search as well... but using matlab... not using grid.py... maybe this helps...

Comment: Sorry I don't understand the return value of function svmtrain. It should be a model that is returned. Why you treat it as an accuracy and what accuracy is it? Thanks!

Comment: @lakesh: here, for this grid search and selecting the parameters, it needs to feed all the data (train and test) as an input to the 'svmtrain' or there is another way to deal with data?

Answer (score 6):

You could use the matlab script provided instead of grid.py FAQ

> Q: How could I use MATLAB interface for parameter selection? 
>   http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvm/faq.html#f803

```
bestcv = 0;
for log2c = -1:3,
  for log2g = -4:1,
    cmd = ['-v 5 -c ', num2str(2^log2c), ' -g ', num2str(2^log2g)];
    cv = svmtrain(heart_scale_label, heart_scale_inst, cmd);
    if (cv >= bestcv),
      bestcv = cv; bestc = 2^log2c; bestg = 2^log2g;
    end
    fprintf('%g %g %g (best c=%g, g=%g, rate=%g)\n', log2c, log2g, cv, bestc, bestg, bestcv);
  end
end
```